# Infinite renderloop, when changing an array, that was called from an API and put into state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a very similiar problem, to a problem, that i had before: [How to execute a function AFTER an API-Call was made with setState within useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72155700/how-to-execute-a-function-after-an-api-call-was-made-with-setstate-within-useeff).

It seems that the useEffect Function, that is calling my API, is running AGAIN after my second useEffect Function was called. So here is what is happening:

1. quizData is an empty array (which is fine for the beginning)
2. quizData is an Array filled with data from the API (but without the key, which is fine at this moment)
3. quizData is then an Array filled with Data from the API and also has the key-property added (so the second useEffect seems to be working). Perfect!
4. quizData is again the Array only filled with data from the API (the key-property is missing, it seems only the first useEffect is running again) Annoying.

Both solutions of the "old question" are unfortunately not working in this case. The only solution, that was working is to disable the strict-mode of react (then the component is not rendered twice). But its not recommended for beginners to do this, because this workaround seem to be a strong indication, that my code is very unstable.

If i change the dependency-array of the second-useEffect from quizData.length to only quizData. I am getting the infinite renderloop and my complete App is crashing.
If it stays quizData.length the second-useEffect is only running once. Which i dont understand, because i thought EVERY useEffect is running at the beginning independently what is in the dependency-array.

So, is there any solution to this, except to disable Strict-Mode? For me it seems a frequent case, that you call something from an API and want to change the data in it.

Here is my codebase:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Start from "./components/Start.js"
import Questions from "./components/Questions.js"
import {nanoid} from "nanoid"


function App() {


  const [start, setStart] = React.useState(true)
  const [quizData, setQuizData] = React.useState(() => [])

  const isInitialRender = React.useRef(true);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {   *//getting the data from the API and put it into an Array*
        
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => 
        {
        isInitialRender.current = false;
        setQuizData(data.results);
        });


        console.log("i am the Boss")

    },[])


   React.useEffect(() => {  *//taking the Array that was created with the API-Call and adding an*
    if(!isInitialRender.current) addKey();
    
      
  }, [quizData.length]) 

  
  console.log(quizData)



    function addKey() {
      setQuizData((prevData) => (prevData.map(element => ({...element, key: nanoid()}))))
    }


    function changeDisplay() {
      setStart(prevState => !prevState)
    }

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {start ? <Start changeDisplay={changeDisplay}/> : <Questions quizData={quizData} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why not add the key inside the fetch callback?

Comment: Interesting. It is working in this case. But it is not very risky? For example if the API-Call is to slow, and the function tries to add something to an array, that is not there?
In my "old question" this was the problem, when i put the function directly into the fetch function. That it doesnt wait and then tried to modify the array, before it was updated with data from the API.

Comment: It's not risky at all if you add the keys in the case of a successful api response. I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't wait", you obviously add the keys inside the success callback where you call `setQuizData`. Because that is the exact moment where the API data was loaded and is definitely available.